# Descriptor example in Python docs does not work

Tags: python

An example taken from Python docs. [Link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html?highlight=property#properties).

```
class Cell(object):
    def getvalue(self, obj):
        "Recalculate cell before returning value"
        self.recalc()
        return obj._value
    value = property(getvalue)
```

But when I do

```
cell = Cell()
cell.value
```

exception raised

```
TypeError: getvalue() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'
```

Question:
How is the example code expected to be used?

Answer (score 2):

I think you've found a bug in the documentation. You can't pass (to my knowledge) arguments to getter-type properties. I think the example should be:

```
class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, cell):
        self.cell = cell

    def recalc(self):
        self._value = 100 # this wouldn't really return a static value

    def getvalue(self):
        "Recalculate cell before returning value"
        self.recalc()
        return self._value
    value = property(getvalue)

>>> Cell('A1').value
100
```